# How can I add another to a string?

Tags: java

whats wrong with my code, i want it so if the string you input is 33*10= it outputs the correct answer, but it outputs 0.0 in this case and if the string was 33+10 it would output 44

```
while (character != '=')
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < calc.length(); i++)
        {
            character = calc.charAt(i);

            try
            {
                    final String characterString = Character.toString(character);
                    characterString = characterString +characterString
                    setOperand(Double.parseDouble(characterString));
                    if (flag == 0)
                    {

                        operand1 = (Double.parseDouble(characterString));

                        result = operand1;
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                    getResult();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    operator = character;
                }
                catch (Exception e2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter a number");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: accept some of your other questions and people would be more willing to help u ^_^

Comment: @Neal, definitely not true. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add char to your String, use StringBuffer:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.add("3+3=");
buffer.add("6");
System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String mainString="i am ready to add characters";
char c='v';

String toAdd=Character.toString(c);

mainString = mainString.concat(toAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `character = calc.charAt(i);` which is only grabbing 1 character try...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(calc.charAt(i).isDigit()){
    sb.append(calc.charAt(i));
    i++;
}
...
final String characterString = sb.toString();
```

Doing this will attach all consecutive digits to the string builder and then turn that into a string to be parsed.

This may work, but your code has a lot of places that it could fail. For instance, you're using exceptions as a decision method, which is typically frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Objects of type String can't be changed after their creation. You have either to build a new String out of the old String an the one you want to append or - way better - use a StringBuilder. If you need synchronization for the String manupilation you would use a StringBuffer instead a StringBuilder. Both are essantially the same but the latter one is threadsafe whereas the first one is not.

```
final String characterString = Character.toString(character);
characterString = characterString +characterString
```

I don' really get what you want to do here. Yes you could use the second line, but there is a problem:

```
characterString +characterString
```

will create a *new* object, thus charactrerString will be assigned a new object. This are you preventing by the `final` statement in the first line.

Moreover `characterString +characterString` would create a String composed by a String repeated 2 times. Like

```
characterString = "123456";
characterString = characterString + characterString;
System.out.print(characterString);
```

Would print `123456123456` in the console. And don't know if this is your intention.

And you are initializing the String characterString inside the loop. So each pass you are creating a new one, discarding the old one. Unnecessary object creation an destruction should be avoided if possible.